# Joomla 2.5 error tranfer from server to local

Tags: joomla2.5

I installed joomla akeeba compatible with Version 2.5
Installation completed successfully
after I save site using "backup now"
Hopefully, jpa file size is 252 MG

the problem when I download the file; it is not compléte download:
I tried several times .
- Example of downloaded FILES: jpa file size of 63 MG, 89 MG; 110 mg but not compléte.

how to solve this problem please.

Comment: not response ??????

Comment: Trying to bump your question twice within an hour or so of posting is probably not the best way to motivate volunteers (or at least this particular volunteer) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Check the version of Akeeba Backup is [the correct one for the version of Joomla and PHP you are using](https://www.akeebabackup.com/compatibility.html):
2. For [various reasons](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/securing-file-transfers.html), you should download the backup file using FTP in binary mode.
3. Read the [excellent documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation.html).